# How to copy database file from one Android device to another

Tags: android, database

I'm swtching to a new phone and need to transfer an app data. That app can export all data into a .db file or import data from the file. So I exported data from my old phone and manually copied the .db file to my new phone. But the app on my new phone does not recognize the database. Is there something in the .db file distinctive to my old phone that resulted in the failure?

Comment: In a .db file?  If its a standard SQLite db file, its common across devices.  If its an encrypted db file then you could be out of luck.

Comment: You better tell how the app on your new phone would know about that database file. You keep it pretty vague.

Comment: Although not a programmer, I actually downloaded the sqlite db browser to view the database file. It was just many tables packed together, and does not seem to contain any identifing information for a specific device. There is not a problem when I export the file and import on the same device. But when I copy the .db file to my PC and paste it back to the phone, it is not recognized. And yes, it's just an export and import botton in the app. I don't know the codings behind it. Sorry.